# Oracle PHP "&nbsp;" becomes "??" on update

Tags: php, html, oracle

I have an application which saves html templates as a clob in an oracle DB.
When I **update** previously saved HTML the `&nbsp;` becomes `??`.

```
$sql = "UPDATE headers 
        SET header_code = :HEADER_CODE
        WHERE header_ID = :HEADER_ID ";
...

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':HEADER_CODE', $form_qs['HEADER_CODE']); 
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':HEADER_ID', $form_qs['HEADER_ID']); 
...
```

> oracle version info:
>  Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition
>   Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
>  PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 -
>   Production
>  "CORE  10.2.0.4.0  Production"
>  TNS for Solaris:
>   Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
>  NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 -
>   Production
>
> PHP Version 5.2.6

Comment: Are entities being decoded at any point in your code? non-breaking spaces use a different character code than regular spaces.

Comment: No I'm not, What to you suggest?

Comment: The nbsp entity is getting converted to the actual unicode character somewhere. I don't think oracle or the prepared statements would do that.

Comment: Again, it's only happening on the update not on the original save so the code is the same. The information in the text area though is different when I first entered the information the HTML entity is shown as typed &nbsp; when I go back to make the update it is displayed as a blank space. I hope this helps.

Comment: In that case, are you sure the string still has &nbsp; before you do the update query? An &nbsp; might be converted in an edit form if you are not encoding entities at that point.

Comment: The Database clearly says &nbsp;

Comment: I understand that. However, I am guessing that on update you are extracting the value from the database then displaying it in a form before sending it back to the server. WHen you put it into the form are you encoding entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after datasage got me to realize this is an encoding issue and not a database issue I refocused my google searching and found it's the textbox (along with my enctype) which is converting the &nbsp; into a 2 character Unicode (I echoed out strlen($form_qs['HEADER_CODE'])).

That being said I'm now replacing the & with &amp; so the textbox will display &nbsp; not a blank space. I hope the solution will not mess other things up but time will tell.

```
str_replace('&','&amp;',$form_qs['HEADER_CODE']);
```

(Thanks DoSparKot and nickb for the formatting help)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about syntax errors in your code, however you can use `oci_new_descriptor()` to open a new descriptor for CLOB

```
<?php
$clob = oci_new_descriptor ($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
oci_bind_by_name ($stid, ':HEADER_CODE', $clob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
$clob->write  ($form_qs['HEADER_CODE']);

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':HEADER_ID', $form_qs['HEADER_ID']);

//after execution/commit
$clob->free();
?>
```

`OCI_D_LOB`: Data of LOB type

`OCI_B_CLOB`: Binding of CLOB type

Comment: I'm not having any syntax errors the code is fine for regular ASCII characters

Comment: Looking at `<br>` in SQL string I thought so. Did above solution work?

Comment: The <br> was just bad formatting on my part. No the solution did not work.